# Haml pass localized variable to partial

Tags: ruby, internationalization, haml, rails-i18n

I'm rendering a Haml partial in my application and I'd like to localize a parameter I'm passing in.

So instead of

```
= render 'form', user: @admin_user, roles: @roles,
  button_name: 'non localized text'
```

I'd like to have something like

```
= render 'form', user: @admin_user, roles: @roles,
  button_name: - t '.localized_text_version'
```

to access my yml variable localization. How would I best do that?

Any input is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently it's

```
= render 'form', user: @admin_user, roles: @roles, 
  button_name: t('.update_admin_user')
```